# Non-linear differential equation existence and uniqueness of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

I am very unfamiliar with the theory of nonlinear differential equations. Is there any result that given some initial conditions ensure the existence and uniqueness of a solution to the following:
$af(x)=c-bf'(x)^2+f'(x)(tx+e)+kf''(x)$
for all $x,a,b,c,t,e,k\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question is formulated sloppily. You need to place restrictions on $k$ Otherwise, the differential equation is simply $$af(x)=c-bf'(x)^2+f'(x)(tx+e),$$ which is a much simpler equation to analyze for $k=0,$ and for $k\neq0,$ the equation simplifies if you divde all constants by $k.$ The constant is redundant in both cases, but which redundancy you have depends on the restriction you put on $k.$ Similarly, if $b=0,$ then this is a much simpler equation to work with. This is also true if $t=0.$ Also, you have unnecessary multiples of $-1,$ and the constant $c$ is redundant.

Comment: The equation should simply be rewrriten as $$f''(x)+Af'(x)^2+(Bx+C)f'(x)+Df(x)=0,$$ where all the constants are nonzero. Even better, one could simplify and have $$f''(x)+k[x+A+Bf'(x)]f'(x) + Cf(x)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately as I said I am very unfamiliar with nonlinear differential equations. I will look for a numerical solution using your simplified form.